# How to include a multiline text in regex pattern

Tags: json, regex, validation

I have a pattern `^[0-9]+$`, but I want it to include a `\n` new-line symbol so that the string like below would be valid:
`123\n345\n678\n9752\n` or in other words:

```
123
345
678
9752
```

Comment: yeah, but something like would be valid, wouldn't it?
"123aaa\nsdasda\nadsada12331231"

Comment: @JvdV no, I mean, if I include any other symbols, it would make the parts with numbers valid, not the whole string invalid

Comment: @JvdV try it on regex101.com, if you add a letter "a" anywhere inside the multiline string of numbers, it'll make valid parts before and after the line with letter

Comment: @JvdV yes! that is totally right, thank you! If you want to make this comment an official answer, i'll vote it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to include leading/trailing newlines, try:

```
\A[0-9]+(?:\n[0-9]+)*\Z
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TyZecH/1).

---

- `\A` - Start-string anchor;
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits;
- `(?:\n[0-9]+)*` - Match nested non-capture group 0+ times validating a single newline character and 1+ digits;
- `\Z` - End-string anchor.

---

**Note**: As per my comments, [`^[0-9]+(?:\n[0-9]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/mHjQy2/1) would also work with the right flags turned on/off.